# VW stick shift shifter lockout

Tags: vw, clutch, manual-transmission, grinding

So my 2007 VW GTI has 257k miles.. (I know.) But it is my daily driver for now. I went on the highway and while I was in 6th, it popped into neutral by itself. I got kinda sketch but I was like okay whatever maybe I didn't move the shifter 100%. Then on my way back I stopped at a red light and went to shift into 1st and it wouldn't let me. I could move the shifter side to side freely but any gear it was locked out of. It DID go into gear but I literally had to push the shifter using about 400% the normal effort. I forced it into 1st, 3rd, then 5th and got home as quick as possible. While driving, I have this grinding sound I can only describe and whacking tinfoil over and over again. The sound stops when the clutch pedal is 100% engaged, but around the 'friction zone' the noise is terrible, even in neutral. I got it home and I'm wondering is it even safe to drive? Is this a quick fix? What are your thoughts?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: With the car stationary, and the engine off, does it go into gear easily?

Comment: You might want to consider the issue raised in this question: https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/37884/hard-shifting-on-2003-vw-jetta-1-8-with-manual-transmission?rq=1

Comment: What was your resolution?